# Is position:absolute without top or bottom a good CSS practice?

Tags: html, css

I have a markup like this:

```
<label>First Name: <input type="text" /></label>
<label>Last Name: <input type="text" /></label>
<label>Email: <input type="text" /></label>
```

And a CSS like this:

```
label{display:block; padding:10px 0;}
input{position:absolute; left:100px;}
```

And it's result is like this in almost every browser I test:

### [image: result]

It works fine while there is no `top` or `bottom` in CSS code for `absolute` positioned `input`s. 
My question is: Is this kind of aligning elements a good practice and are you know any issue with a browser with this kind of positioning?

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3eaa/) of the code.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "semantic?" Do you just mean "valid?" If it's the latter, you can use the [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) if you're ever unsure.

Comment: I changed my wording and also added the fiddle link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS does not have to be semantic. Semantic HTML means that the tags, identifiers and classes have meaning.

CSS is purely representational and does not have to have meaning.

And absolute positioning without defining top and bottom is perfectly OK (it just defaults to `auto`)

Comment: I changed my wording. I just wanted to make sure it will work in any browser

Comment: @Mohsen: I suppose in case of auto the browser has to compute the value of auto.

Comment: Yes, and the browser will calculate it after these rules: [top](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-top), [bottom](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-bottom), [left and right](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width).

Answer (score 4):

`position:absolute;` takes an element out of the normal flow. If you just want to move the element a bit, `position:relative;` is a way better choice - you can give an offset to the original coordinates instead of having the coordinates depend on the elements around. For more details, refer to the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position).

CSS has no notion of "semantic", it just styles anything, `div` or `article`.

Comment: I changed the word "semantic". absolute positioned element will obey it's static positioned parent's position flow if it's position set to auto. and also will apply it's relative positioned parent as it's base point

Comment: According to the text at your link, elements with `position:fixed` are repeated on every page, not elements with `position:absolute`.

Comment: @Alohci Oops, you're totally right. I misread that. Removed the wrong passage.

Answer (score 0):

Side issue in your code: Explicitly associating labels with their controls is preferred:

```
<label for="fname">First Name:</label> <input id="fname" type="text" />
<label for="lname">Last Name:</label> <input id="lname" type="text" />
<label for="email">Email:</label> <input id="email" type="text" />
```

to Implicit association (wrapping the controls in the label like you have.)

[See WCAG 2.0 Technique 44](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced position absolute without "top/left/bottom/right" with margin set (negative one if necessary) had saved solved my strange problem repositioning element in various modern browsers. Element is taken out of the normal flow as its position is no longer calculated against its container.

Adding top/left/bottom/right make the default (correct) behaviour to apply - the element in question looks for closest parent with position relative / absolute then adjusts its position.